# Counting Employees, but Split By Line Manager - PowerBI - DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some tables in PBI called

Staffmaster - This has columns Unique ID, Start Date, End Date, SLT
Date - This is a Date Table
EOM which is a custom table I used to count employees at the end of each month. It has columns End of Month ( a list of dates which are the end of month), EmployeeCount (which is a count of employees at the date in the first column)

I use the EmployeeCOunt column to provide a visual that can show me the number of employees at each month end. The measure is calculated as follows:

`EmployeeCount =  CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Staffmaster)), FILTER( Staffmaster, Staffmaster[Start Date] <= EARLIER(EOM[End of Month]) && (ISBLANK(Staffmaster[End Date]) || Staffmaster[End Date] >= EARLIER(EOM[End of Month])) ) )`

This works perfect in the realms of simple counts for how many staff at each month end. However, someone then asked can I split this so I can use a slicer to see how many people were employed at month end by SLT which is in the Staffmaster table.

For the life of me I cant figure out a way to amend what I have to take account of the slicer for SLT. Any suggestions :)

I cant get it to display the correct results. I tried:

```
EmployeesCount =
VAR SelectedManager = SELECTEDVALUE('staffmaster'[slt]) // Get selected manager
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('staffmaster'), 
    FILTER(
        'staffmaster',
        'staffmaster'[slt] = SelectedManager && // Filter by selected manager
        'staffmaster'[start date] <= MAX('Calendar'[Date]) && // Check start date
        ('staffmaster'[end date] >= MAX('Calendar'[Date]) || ISBLANK('staffmaster'[end date])) // Check end date
    )
)
```

but it didnt work